# Upgrade django-haystack from 2.4.1 to 2.5.0 not working

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack, whoosh

I want to upgrade django-haystack in my app from 2.4.1 to 2.5.0.
On version 2.4.1 my code works fine. But when I installed verison 2.5.0 I get error when I start searching, for example: New york and I dont have any search results.

```
"GET /en/search?q=new%20york HTTP/1.1" 500 26693

Exception Value:    
'MainSearchView' object has no attribute 'context_class'
```

Comment: Have you got a stacktrace? Without details of the error encountered it's impossible to say what may be wrong...

Comment: @markwalker_ I have only this: `"GET /en/search?q=new%20york HTTP/1.1" 500 26693` website is working but I didn't get any results of searching with 2.5.0 or 2.6.0 version. On 2.4.1 working fine. I want to upgrade because in 2.5.0 they fixed bug.

Comment: If that's in production, a 500 should trigger an email to your `ADMINS` setting; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/error-reporting/
There you'll get your stacktrace. Either that or your server error log will have info in, depending on how your server is configured.

Comment: This is not production server, I'm working on this on my local machine.

Comment: In that case you'll have the stacktrace in your console from where you're running the server. Are you running in debug mode?

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: Post your `MainSearchView`. I suspect that is your view for search, which doesn't implement `context_class()`. RTD; https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.0/views_and_forms.html#new-django-class-based-views